# tensor product of modules over algebra and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have always wondered this statement is true.

> Let $S$ be commutative algebra over $R$ and $M,N$ be modules over $S$. Then, $M\otimes_R N\simeq M\otimes_S N$ as $S$-modules. (Or can be as $R$-modules.)

Why I think it is true: A map between two modules can be induced by universal property of tensor product; $m\otimes n\mapsto m\otimes n$. Surjectivity is trivial and injectivity may be shown by the definition of tensor product. (Actually, it is a quotient module of a free module.)

So what I want to know is: is this known to be true? Or just this is my mistake.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "triviality" of the injectivity? I might be missing something but I can't see why this is true.

Comment: you mean triviality of surjectivity

Comment: Injectivity is not true in general

Comment: Sorry, I meant surjectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false: the only result we have is the canonical homomorphism $\;M\otimes_R N\longrightarrow M\otimes_SN\; $ is surjective.

As a counter-example, consider $\mathbf C$ as a vector space on $\mathbf R$: then $\dim_\mathbf{R}(\mathbf C\otimes_\mathbf{R}\mathbf C) =4$, whereas  $\dim_\mathbf{R}(\mathbf C\otimes_\mathbf{C}\mathbf C)=\dim_\mathbf{R}\mathbf C=2 $.